# How can I close tab by title or url from command line in ubuntu firefox?

Tags: linux, bash, firefox, terminal

OS: Ubuntu 20.4.03LTS | Firefox version : Mozilla Firefox 93.0

I have Only one Firefox window opened, in that window there are lot of tabs, I need a way to close a specific tab by title or Url from command line, something like:
`close_tab_command https://www.olx.com.pk/item/king-side-beds-for-sale-iid-1039955840`

Comment: Did you find a way to do it?

Comment: @DrClaw Not yet

Answer (score 0):

[brotab](https://github.com/balta2ar/brotab/) -
*Control your browser's tabs from the command line*

**UPDATE**

**Preparing to use**

add an extension to your browser (mozilla/chrome)

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/brotab/

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/brotab/mhpeahbikehnfkfnmopaigggliclhmnc/

installation

https://github.com/balta2ar/brotab/#installation

don't forget to make

```
$ brotab install
```

**Using**

```
$ brotab --help
...
    list                list available tabs. The command will request all available clients
                        (browser plugins, mediators), and will display browser tabs in the
                        following format: "<prefix>.<window_id>.<tab_id><Tab>Page title<Tab>URL"
    close               close specified tab IDs. Tab IDs should be in the following format:
                        "<prefix>.<window_id>.<tab_id>". You can use "list" command to obtain tab
                        IDs (first column)

$ brotab list
a.1.2   Title URL
a.1.3   ...
a.1.4   ...

$ brotab close a.1.3

$ brotab list
a.1.2   ...
a.1.4   ...
```

Comment: AFAIK the `brotab` is used to list down the opened tabs' urls, we can't close a specific tab using it.

Comment: @amir-saleem you can close tabs, see answer update